# Semantic UI - `gulp build` returns JS error

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, semantic-ui

I installed the latest version of Semantic-UI but when building the assets with `gulp build`, compiling JS returns the errors below, while CSS is compiled just fine.

```
Building assets
[10:48:00] Created: dist/components/site.js
[10:48:00] Plumber found unhandled error:
 GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: DefaultsError: `preserveComments` is not a supported option
File: /home/forge/mysite.co/public/semantic/dist/components/site.js
[10:48:00] Created: dist/components/form.js
[10:48:00] Plumber found unhandled error:
 GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: DefaultsError: `preserveComments` is not a supported option
File: /home/forge/mysite.co/public/semantic/dist/components/form.js
[10:48:00] Created: dist/components/accordion.js
[10:48:00] Plumber found unhandled error:
 GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: DefaultsError: `preserveComments` is not a supported option
File: /home/forge/mysite.co/public/semantic/dist/components/accordion.js
[10:48:00] Created: dist/components/checkbox.js
[10:48:00] Plumber found unhandled error:
 GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: DefaultsError: `preserveComments` is not a supported option
File: /home/forge/mysite.co/public/semantic/dist/components/checkbox.js
[10:48:00] Created: dist/components/dimmer.js
[10:48:00] Plumber found unhandled error:
 GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: DefaultsError: `preserveComments` is not a supported option
File: /home/forge/mysite.co/public/semantic/dist/components/dimmer.js
```

I have never come across this issue before in my previous projects with Semantic UI so I'm not sure what is causing this. Can anybody suggest the fix?

Answer (score 0):

This bug is being fixed. See here:

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/5391